# ASP.net DAL get ID of record just inserted

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-access-layer, uniqueidentifier

```
        // Add into DB
        int recordID = 0;
        using (tblArtworkTemplatesTableAdapter tblAdapter = new tblArtworkTemplatesTableAdapter())
        {
            tblAdapter.Insert(DateTime.Now, int.Parse(lstChooseSpec.SelectedValue), Master.loginData.loggedInUser.ID);
            recordID = int.Parse(tblAdapter.GetLastID().ToString());
        }

        // Redirect
        Response.Redirect("artworkDesigner.aspx?ID=" + recordID);
```

The stored procedure it's calling is:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLastID]
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
select @@identity FROM tblArtworkTemplates
```

I can't seem to get it to work, I'm a newb with this DAL stuff any help appreciated!

Comment: You probably want to use SCOPE_IDENTITY instead. Here is more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: This is one of those comments that you really need a macro on StackOverflow, like "use JQuery", but you ought to take a look at Entity Framework...it makes a lot of all of this wiring-type of code go up in smoke. I did this mess for years, and I will never go back. If you don't like EF, check out NHibernate.

Comment: ... or even plain old LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that this is SQL Server? You should return the ID of the newly inserted record from your INSERT INTO stored procedure. For more on `@@Identity`see [@@IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx)

Return the ID of the newly inserted record from your stored procedure:

```
SELECT ID AS LastID FROM tblArtworkTemplates WHERE ID = @@Identity;
```

Fore more on the topic see [How To Get Last Inserted ID On SQL Server](http://www.beansoftware.com/T-SQL-FAQ/Get-Last-Inserted-ID.aspx).

Comment: @ marc_s Good point since @@Identity isn't limited to a specific scope. Thanks for your input.